# Redirect command output to file - only when stdout has been closed from the command

Tags: bash, stdout

Title should explain it all. I have a program whose stdout takes a lot to complete - i want to completely redirect the output to a file, but only when the output is complete and the command is closed. How can i do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: [@jordanm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9690605/96588) is right, but you should ask yourself *why* you're doing this. Linux programs are good at handling streams, and the program will be *much* faster if you don't write to disk before continuing with the next command.

Comment: It's not a program, it's a 1-line script. The goal is to get the zpool iostat output written to a file that I can always parse. A total of 1 IO operation per 5 minutes. Belive me, this do has a sense =)

Comment: Yep, that's a perfect case for it. Getting a habit to point it out though, since it's common to use Too Many Files(TM) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to store the output in a variable. I do not recommend this if the output is very large.

```
output=$(command)
printf "$output" > logfile
```

Comment: Thanks. (i should have arrived to this by my own)

Comment: Sometimes over-thinking a problem can cause us to miss simple solutions.

Comment: Or if you don't want an extra trailing newline (or the command always outputs a trailing newline), `echo -n "$output" > logfile`.

Comment: You should use `"$(command)"` to avoid [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: @l0b0 - word splitting does not occur on the right side of an assignment. `echo` changed to `printf`

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming to have the output both on the terminal and in the file:

> ```
> NAME
>        tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
> ```

(from `man tee`)

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was about.

Comment: My goal would be to have the output only to a file. I want the input to be written only when the command is complete. Thinking about it i think i could simply use bash vars...